# Avro schema optional array as null

Tags: arrays, apache-kafka, avro

I can't serialize the data when the array attribute has `null`. I'm using [KafkaAvroSerializer](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaAvroSerializer.java).class for `value.serializer` property

Testing.avsc:

```
{ "namespace": "com.kafka.schema", "name": "Testing", "type": "record", "fields": [{ "name": "names", "type" : { "type": "array", "items": [ "null", "string" ], "default": [] } }] }
```

Error:
Caused by: `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message` Caused by: `java.lang.NullPointerException: null of array of com.kafka.schema.Testing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array itself can be null, I would wrote `null` as an accepted `type`, and not as an accepted value in the array.

```
{
   "namespace":"com.kafka.schema",
   "name":"Testing",
   "type":"record",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"names",
         "type":[
            {
               "type":"array",
               "items":[
                  "null",
                  "string"
               ],
               "default":[

               ]
            },
            "null"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: It creates the topic with some junk characters. When I try to read the topic it throws the below error<br><br/>
org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.ConversionException: Failed to convert from JSON; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): only regular white space (\r, \n, \t) is allowed between tokens
 at [Source: (String)"      "; line: 1, column: 2]

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write `It creates the message` instead of  `It creates the topic`? How do you read the content of the topic? It's strange that your exception is about `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException`. Do not forget that the content of your topic is serialized in Avro. So you should use the KafkaAvroDeserializer when you consume the messages.

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I used JsonDeserializer. Works perfectly after changing it to KafkaAvroDeserializer. Thank you :)